# StringCchCat does not append source string to destination string

Tags: c++, string, winapi, access-violation

I'm having a hard time understanding why my code isn't working. I've spend days breaking my head over this. I'm hoping someone can help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to append one string (LPCTSTR) to another (LPTSTR) using StringCchCat.

```
//LPTSTR tempPath = _T(""); 
LPTSTR tempPath = new TCHAR[MAX_PATH];
LPCTSTR src = _T("Text to append");
StringCchCat(tempPath, MAX_PATH, src);
std::wcout << tempPath << std::endl;
```

However, the src string does not get appended to the destination. On printing, it prints a blank line.

I'm looked around to see if I am initializing the tempPath variable correctly and based on other stackoverflow threads it seems to be fine. I initially tried initializing it using the _T(), however, this gives me an 'Access Violation' error when it attempts to append the strings with StringCchCat

I'm relatively new to C++ and am unsure as to why the string isn't getting appended.

(This code is a stripped down version of a larger block of code - I do need to use StringCchCat and the string types used in the block above)

Comment: You are appending to an uninitialized string buffer.

Comment: @RaymondChen - I did try initializing to a NULL string. (tempPath  = _T(""), but it gives me an 'Access Violation' on running StringCchCat

Comment: That is not the same as allocating a buffer and initializing it. That is using an existing (read-only) buffer. I think you need to brush up on memory management.

Comment: @RaymondChen - What exactly would I need to look into? I'm relatively new to c++ and I'm not sure what specifically to look into.

Comment: Start with a text book